# Firebase Messaging and PathProvider show warnings when running the app - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This warning is shown after I had added `firebase_messaging`, `firebase_core` and `flutter_local_notifications`.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on BE2013 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-11.2.15\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\JobIntentService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the followings in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.7
  firebase_core: ^1.12.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.4.1
```

Which will show one warning:

```
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-11.2.7/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/messaging/JobIntentService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Run console message:

```
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51033/8pCW_5FSPDM=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 arm64...
```